# DataAnnotationsExtensionsMVC3 validation not working on Integer value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

Getting default error message for int datatype
i.e `he value 'abc' is not valid for age`

What should i do.

```
   public class HomeViewModel
   {
    [Integer(ErrorMessage="provide valid numeric value")}
    public int age{ get; set; }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your action method that you post data to ,did you check if the model is valid ?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyActionMethod(Model model)
{
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     return View(model);
  }
  //else post data
}
```

---

if you want to display error message for the `Integer` you can try

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Age Is Required")]
[Integer(ErrorMessage="Numbers Only")]
public int Age { get; set; }
```

Comment: if there is still a prob please post your view , model and controller code

Comment: i even not able to decorete my int property with [Integer]

Comment: ensure you imported the proper namespace
    `[Integer]
    public int Age { get; set; }` works

Comment: on the top of your file put `using DataAnnotationsExtensions;`

Comment: if you put that line and there is a compile problem use nuget again and add reference because the dll is not referenced by that project

Comment: but i am not getting the error message i wrote [Integer(ErrorMessage="provide valid numeric value")]

Comment: your getting the default error message ? not the custom message , or no message at all ?